# Парсинг сайта с помощью ehp

Tags: html, python, парсер

Как запарсить html с помощью библиотеки ehp,

Например:

```
<div class='firstdiv>
<a href='https://ссылка.ru'>
</div>
```

Чтобы вывести именно [https://ссылка.ru](https://%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0.ru) ?

Comment: Для чего Вам эта библиотека? Не совсем ясно, почему нельзя использовать регулярки

Comment: Извините за встречный вопрос, а почему именно `ehp`? На PyPI даже описания этой библиотеки нет. Может, Вам стоит воспользоваться `beautifulsoup4`?

Comment: @hedgehogues Вы просто обязаны посмотреть [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11558617) :D H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: А, госпади. Кажется, что кто-то хочет натянуть сову на глобус. По-моему, если задача состоит в том, что нужно выдернуть ссылку, то регэкспы подходят для того очень даже. Если мы говорим про парсинг полноценный, то `scrapy` или `beautifulsoup4` вам в руки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отличным решением будет использовать специальный инструмент для этого, а именно `bs4`.

Для установки введите в терминале (или консоле):

```html
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="firstdiv">
    <a href="https://ссылка.ru">
</div>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elms = bs.select('div.firstdiv a')

for x in elms:
    print(x.attrs['href'])
```

*stdout:*

```html
https://ссылка.ru
```

***P. S.:***
Ваш `HTML` не валиден. Вы забыли закрыть скобку у класса в `div`. Я поправил это. Также для наглядности сделал отступ.

Comment: у автора в примере 1 ссылка, для чего вы тогда ищите несколько ссылок?

Comment: @danilshik Возвращается список. Я, конечно, мог бы обратиться так: `elms[0]`, но решил, что цикл более универсален. Незначительно, но может помочь и тем, у кого ссылок более одной.

Comment: ну тогда бы использовали select_one а не select

Comment: @danilshik Я делаю ставку на универсальность. Этот код полностью удовлетворяет требованиям вопроса. Если он в перспективе поможет не только автору, это прекрасно. Незачем делать его узкоспециализированным под конкретный кусок `HTML`. Я только рад, если вместо полного переписывания и поиска методов, можно изменить пару символов и добиться иного результата. Думаю, продолжать это обсуждение бессмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаком с библиотекой ehp (написал код с помощью selenium, возможно натолкнет на какие-нибудь мысли с использованием ehp)

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

browser = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.maximize_window() 
url = 'ссылка на сайт'
while browser.current_url != url:
    browser.get(url)
while True:
    try:
        element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='firstdiv']")
        info = str(browser.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', element))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
    else:
        break
print(info)
```

Этот код выведет всю информацию об element. Если необходима информация о конкретном атрибуте, то можно воспользоваться методом get_attribute('атрибут элемента')

Надеюсь хоть немного помог :)

Comment: самый фиговый способ использовать Selenium, если можно это спарсить другими библиотеками для парсинга

Comment: Я не знаком с другими библиотеками, поэтому не могу оспорить ваш комментарий, на за 1.5 года работы с этой библиотекой мне не встретилось ни одной задачи (связанной с парсингом данных с сайта), с которой Selenium не смог бы справиться, и пришлось бы использовать иные библиотеки.

Comment: Использовать Selenium для парсинга HTML, это пытаться попасть в воробья из гаубицы. Неудобно. Сложно. Да и не факт, что попадёшь. :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 тогда для чего нужен Selenium?

Comment: @V.Bychkov Как пример, тестирование скриптов Js, тестирование вёрстки, парсинг динамически-генерируемого контента и т. д. Конечно, его можно использовать для парсинга непосредственно, но это очевидно неудобно.